# How to automate assignment to a class from output of a function in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe, class

I am trying desperately to automate some model testing in lme4::lmer (as I have too many to do)

The functions I use run some models and find the best one by checking their stats, and create `res` (that has two Lists in it.
`res$res` is a data frame

`res$res$model` is the text I need rerun the best model (to clear it out, I only use 1)

`res$fits` is a List of 1, with `res$fits[1]` being a "Formal Class 'lmerMod' with 13 slots, the name of which is always exactly the same as `models`

Here's some code to make more sense:

```
models <- theBigList
## run function
res <- fit.func(models=models, response='bnParam1')
# show model selection table
res$res

# This is where you get the best model from above and put it in here to set it up for plotting.
# 
models <- res$res$model[1]

# run function
res <- fit.func(models=models, response='bnParam1')

## model selection table
res$res

# Once you get a model where the best result is the same as the "previous" one you copy and paste it in here to graph it.
# It will be the one with the the lowest CV.R2 from the 2nd 'models'  

top.fit <- res$fits$'INSERT models HERE'
#top.fit is a class lmerMod, and has the list of everything needed to be extracted and calculated to ggplot it
```

Normally I copy and paste the text for the best model into the space where it says 'INSERT models HERE', but I would like to automate it.

I can't seem to use models as an input, nor force it, eg `as.Class` or `as.String`, things like that, nor use other ways of referencing from a list. I am at a loss as to how to assign the right variable.

EDIT #######

So `res$res` is the first List in `res` that is a data frame, it will output something like this:

```
> res$res
model                       nPar      D      aic d.aic w.aic        R2     cv.R2
1 Sp + (1|Spec) + SE + TC   51 3804.244 3906.244     0     1 0.6376789 0.2586369
```

To expand on my last sentence which is the most important. Normally the last bit of code passes the parameters to lme4::fixef like this for e.g.:

`top.fit <- res$fits$"Sp + (1|Spec) + SE + TC"`

This line of code *also* has the last part of that (that I discovered earlier but changes everytime I run a different analysis):

```
models <- res$res$model[1]
> models
[1] "Sp + (1|Spec) + SE + TC"
```

So I'd basically like to put to something like this `top.fit <- res$fits$models` but I assume there is some form of Type incompatibility or problem with using 'models' within the reference to the List/Class?

Comment: Is it possible for you to make this question reproducible? See a guide here to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269

Comment: I'm afraid that is beyond the scope of my current skillset :)
I will edit and try to explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single square brackets were changing the class to a list which wasn't working.

I solved this by referencing with double square brackets, which stopped the conversion, and passes the List as the original lmerMod Class it needs to be. Now I know.

`top.fit <- res$fits[[1]]`